# How is performance affected by the dispatching of numerous actions in a React and Redux app?

Tags: performance, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

How big of an effect do actions have on performance, more precisely: dispatching said actions?

Let's say the same action is dispatched 10 times in a row on a single user interaction with the UI, how would that affect performance? Or, does it even affect performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It primarily depends if React batches the following render. You can either have one render or one dispatch per render - that's totally up to React. Normally React batches in event handlers and effects, but not in async code. You can manually control this by using the `batch` api (re-exported with that name in react-redux).

Generally though, the recommendation is to dispatch *one* action that described what happened and all the necessary information and let any number of reducers react to that. Keep your logic out of your application layer (=React) and inside of your business layer (=Redux).

https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters
https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action
https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-dispatching-many-actions-sequentially

Comment: Thanks! You said about dispatching one single action, so I'm guessing that I should always keep my actions to a minimum, correct? If it is, then is it recommended to use the same approach for async thunks? For instance, I need to call 2 API endpoints, and I do it through 2 async thunks, each for 1 enpoint. Should I create 1 single async thunk instead, and call both API endpoints from there?

Comment: That is pretty much up to you and also up to the question if you want to track the loading status for them together or separately. A few actions are no problem, but 10 actions for a single click is just not a good usage of Redux patterns.